# Настроить запуск приложения в определенное время в iOS с проигрыванием музыки?

Tags: ios, swift4

Приложение должно срабатывать как будильник. В исходном состоянии приложение в бекграунде (1 случай) или выгружено из памяти (2 случай).

В назначенное время оно должно проснуться и запустить проигрывание звукового файла (либо музыкального потока с удаленного сервера)

Каким образом можно реализовать такое поведение (в iOS 10+, Swift 4)? Точно можно сделать - видел такие будильники в приложениях-радио.

Comment: Реализация обработки оповещений не решит данную проблему?

Comment: Существует встроенный менеджер Background-активности. Не знаю, можно ли при помощи него запускать приложение. Я бы реализовал это при помощи уведомлений. Но музыку из онлайн-потока таким образом запустить нельзя.